# ember-cli addon component not finding npm module

Tags: javascript, ember.js, npm, ember-cli

I am trying to use an npm module in a component so I installed ember-browserify to be able to import the module, but for some reason it is not being found.

This is how I am trying to import it:

```
import dropzone from 'npm:dropzone'
```

this is the error I am getting

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `dropzone` imported from `<Project Name>/components/drop-zone/component`
```

I don't think it's supposed to be looking for the module there.

I have the npm in the package.json

Do I need to install something else? Is there an extra step I am missing?

EDIT: this is an ember-cli addon

Answer (score 1):

To use the `'npm:'` shortcut you need the awesome [ember-browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify) addon. Don't forget to star it!

Simply install it into your project via `ember install ember-browserify`, restart the dev server and it'll work.

Provided that you've had installed the dependency via `npm install --save-dev dropzone`, of course. ;)

Comment: ```Install failed. Could not find addon with name: ember-browserify```
it has to be installed via npm.